# Is the following statement about polynomial approximation of non-differentiable functions true?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, proof-writing, approximation, lagrange-interpolation

### Statement

$\forall L \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and $\forall f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which

- $f$ isn't differentiable at point $a\in\mathbb{R}$
- $f$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere else (on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{a\}$)
- $\lim_{x\to a-} f'(x) \ne \lim_{x\to a+} f'(x)$

$\forall p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ polynomials the following holds:

$$\Rightarrow |\{x\in\mathbb{R}: |f(x)-p(x)|>L\}| = |\mathbb{R}|$$

### Explanation

This function $f$ has a nondifferentiable point $a$, but it *is* differentiable in an area around $a$, with the limits of the derivative of $f$ being different on both ends on $a$. For example the function

$$f(x)=|x|$$

has such a point at $a=0$, with the limits of its derivative being $-1$ from the left, and $+1$ from the right:

$$\lim_{x\to a-} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to a-} -1 = -1 \ne 1 = \lim_{x\to a+} 1 = \lim_{x\to a+} f'(x)$$

In general, these functions look something like this near the point $a$ (Here I set $a=0$):

[image: Non differentiable function at a]

The statement says that such functions **cannot be approximated by any polynomial** $p$, because no matter what polynomial we choose, there will always be uncountably infinitely many $(|\mathbb{R}|)$ points that are arbitrarily far away from $f$ (here, distance $L$ away).

### Intuition

For $f(x) = |x|$, this seems to hold empirically. If we try to fit a Lagrange polynomial onto $n=3,5,7,9,11,13$ points located on the $|x|$ function, we get (an increasingly worse and worse) result:

[image: Polynomial approximation of |x|]

While the polynomial seems to fit nicely near the origin, further away, it completely fails to capture the shape of $|x|$.

Similarly, for a generalized absolute value function

$$V_{l,r}(x) = \begin{cases}lx \quad \text{if } x < 0 \\rx \quad \text{if } x \ge 0 \end{cases}$$

which has a slope of $l$ on $\mathbb{R}^-$ and a slope of $r$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$, we can assume that the above method would also not work.

### Potential proof

We would first of all need to rigorously prove that the statement holds for $V_{l,r}$ for any $l$ (left) input and any $r$ (right) input. This helps because any function defined in the statement is **locally a generalized absolute value function** $V_{l,r}$ near $a$.

So after seeing that polynomial approximation doesn't work for $V_{l,r}$, it also cannot work for functions defined in the statement, since it already doesn't work in the local area of $a$.

However, there is an issue. The fact that the approximation doesn't work locally, does not directly mean that the approximation polynomial will be distance $L$ away from $f$ in uncountably infinitely many points. As we saw earlier, we *can* give a good approximation for $f$ near $a$, but the approximation only fails further away from $a$.

Nonetheless, the fact that polynomial approxmation doesn't work for the "simplest case" of $|x|$, would likely mean that it also doesn't work for more complex functions which are also non-differentiable at a point.

### Context

I have answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487523/is-there-a-no-free-lunch-theorem-for-polynomial-approximation/4487582#4487582) about a "No Free Lunch" theorem for polynomial approximation. This would be my proposed theorem, but I couldn't rigorously prove it myself. It intuitively seems to hold, as long as it is true that $f(x)=|x|$ cannot be efficiently approxmated by polynomials, which again, seems to hold from testing.

Comment: Is the $\forall L$ at the beginning a typo? Your assumptions are (universally) quantified over by $L,$ but $L$ doesn't appear anywhere in your assumptions. It might help to clearly identify the $P$ and the $Q$ (including any quantifiers, with their scopes clearly indicated) in your $P \Rightarrow Q$ theorem statement. It also might help if you indicate at the beginning the difference between what you're doing and the [Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) that most people seeing this will probably think of.

Comment: It is a universal quantor, it's not a typo. It does appear in the statement, at the end. But I'll edit my post to clarify the $P \Rightarrow Q$.

Comment: The difference is, $p$ is meant to be a *global* approximation for $f$, but the statement says, that there will be uncountably infinitely many points where $p$ is arbitrarily far away from $f$ (distance $L$ away).

Comment: Did you ever draw the Taylor polynomials of degree $n$ for, say, $\sin x$ as $n\to\infty$? These polynomials also go bonkers as $|x|\to\infty$, yet over any finite interval, they approximate $\sin$ uniformly.  This also holds for $|x|$ due to the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Yes, that's true. My statement could nonetheless be right anyway.

Comment: @lcv It's trivally true for small values of $L$. Most values are further apart than $10^{-5}$. The interesting case is when $L$ is large. (That's why I chose to use "$L$" instead of $\varepsilon$. :D )

Comment: I think people are confused because I'm not saying these types of functions can be well approximated. I'm saying they **cannot**. The original statement contains $> L$, not $< L$. But this is explained in the later sections multiple times, so I thought I made it clear.

Comment: Yes you're right (in the way I got confused)

Comment: Please write your question either in mathematical English or in formal logic, not a mixture of the two. You write two statements: "$\forall L \ldots$" and "$\forall p \ldots$" under the heading "**Statement**": what does that mean?

Comment: @RobArthan It's the same statement. It has 3 $\forall$'s, ($\forall L, \forall f, \forall p$), followed by an implication.

Comment: That doesn't make anything clearer. Try writing it in English.